# WCF Client Certificate AND UserName Credentials forbidden

Tags: c#, wcf, security, client-certificates

I'm having issues getting a WCF client to connect to a server that requires a client certificate and also a username / password.

I have verified that using JUST the client certificate works using this:

```
        var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.Security.Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity();
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

        var ea = new EndpointAddress(EndpointUrl);

        using (var p = new ServiceReference1.AAAClient(binding, ea))
        {
            try
            {
                p.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
                        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                        CertificateSubject);

                var x = p.RequiresClientCertificateOnly();
                Console.WriteLine("Status: " + x.status);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

The next logical step was to add the username / password parts, but it comes back with 403 unauthorised. I know the credentials and the certificate are valid as I have used fiddler in the middle to provide the client certificate and username / password and it works fine, just when using all through WCF it doesnt seem to work, or use send both the client certificate and the username / password.

The code trying to use both is below (tried with WSHttpBinding and BasicHttpBinding - same result for both):

```
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

        var ea = new EndpointAddress(EndpointUrl);

        using (var p = new ServiceReference1.PingPortTypeClient(binding, ea))
        {
            try
            {
                p.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
                        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                        CertificateSubject);

                p.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Username;
                p.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;

                var x = p.pingDatabase();
                Console.WriteLine("Status: " + x.status);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
```

When I goto the URL directly in a browser - I get the error:

> HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden The page you are attempting to access
>   requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client
>   certificate that the Web server recognizes.

This to suggests that the certificate is not being sent in the second example above as it is the same error (403) being received.

Can someone please help me with the configuration for WCF to provide the client certificate AND the username / password? I have trawled the web, and the 'similar questions' on here have not helped at all. Getting very frustrate by it now - what am i missing?

Comment: can u please show me the web.config?

Comment: are you creating the WCF service also or are you only consuming it. If you are creating the WCF service then do not have client certificate and username/password authentication at the same endpoint. create two different endpoints with each authentication mode (Separation of concerns principal) :)

Comment: OK, I think I see the problem, but I don't see an easy fix. 

You have the SSL working. Based on the code, you're using SSL to encrypt your message, but you're also using Message-level encryption to preserve the client authentication user credentials you're passing to the host.  

WHy are you using both UserName/ID and client certificate credentials to authenticate to the host? I've been working with WCF, encryption and client credentials for a while and I've never seen anyone try to use both.

Comment: @rauts only consuming a 3rd Parties service

Comment: @Brian SSL / client cert is over transport, username for message. Implementing end point exposed by 3rd party, so no say in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a custom binding if you want both username (message level) and certificate (transport level). For example:

```
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="NewBinding0">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Default" />
                <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
                    <secureConversationBootstrap />
                </security>
                <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
```

The value of messageVersion depends if you want to use WSHttp or BasicHttp. Currently I've set it to "Default" which is WSHttp, for Basic set it to "Soap11".

Comment: Thank you so much, that got me 95% there and now all working. Found it surprisingly difficult to find any examples like this out there!

Comment: @RM Can you comment on how you made it to 100%? Because your question mirrors nearly identically what I'm trying to do...right down to the code. Also, does this binding go on the WCF Service as well as the client?

Comment: Also, other than this binding, did you have to alter your code, or other WCF web.config values?

Answer (score 0):

## Username and certificate both on transport level

Not an answer to this question, but the question title brought me here, so maybe others also:
I needed a Soap11-binding with both certificate (for the gateway) and username on transport level (for the application).  (Both parts were maintained by different teams and different suppliers at the customer site.)

Despite the name a `customBinding` with `UserNameOverTransport` sends the username&password in the Soap-header (message-level), not in the http-header (transport-level), leading to this inner `FaultException` in `SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply`, originating from the application:

```
FaultException: MustUnderstand headers: [{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood.
```

And using `basicHttpBinding` with `<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">` leads to:

```
The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: via
```

After a ***lot*** of trial and error, it turned out this can be done by combining configuration and code.

### Example of certificate over transport by configuration

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myBasicHttpBindingForTransportCertificate">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myCertificateBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="my certificate subject" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
```

(I dynamically loaded it, using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33242499).)

### Example of username&password over transport by code

```
using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    …
    var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] =
           "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
```

(Thanks to this old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546086) to "WCF TransportCredentialOnly not sending username and password".)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the following solutions works for me:

```
public class AddBasicAuthenticationClientMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        httpRequestProperty.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));

        request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestProperty);

        return null;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
    }
}

public class AddBasicAuthenticationClientMessageInspectorEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new AddBasicAuthenticationClientMessageInspector());
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}

var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
    
var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://...");
    
var client = new MyPortTypeClient(binding, endpointAddress);
                client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("certificate.pfx", "{certificate_password}");

client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new AddBasicAuthenticationClientMessageInspectorEndpointBehavior());
```